# Failover to different Google AppEngine Standard project

Tags: google-app-engine, failover

I got a Google AppEngine Standard app running in region1 and want to deploy that same app as a backup region2 in case region1 is down. I'm looking for a way to make that failover happens seemlessly for my users (both human users on browsers and other third party services which call back to my app's service).

Currently I have my custom domain name (both naked name and www name) mapped to the app on region #1 (done in [Google Cloud Console][App Engine][Settings][Customer Domains]).

In the event region1 is down, I would like to go in that setting area of app1(region1), remove those maps and then go that setting area of app2(region2) add those maps, so that after that point, requests to myappdomainname.com and www.myappdomainname.com will go to app2 on region2

Question: is that plan feasible? In particular, if region1 is down, can I still be able to access app1's setting area to remove those maps, so that I can add the maps to app2?

Down time while switching these for about an hour is okay for my app, as long as my users can continue to use the same URL they been using when region1 was still running.

Answer (score 1):

Google App Engine is [a regional service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/locations), meaning that it cannot span to more than a region. However, it's replicated through all zones of the region to reduce any potential downtime.

The kind of implementation you want for GAE is opposite of the actual purpose of it. One of GAE's principal features is that you don't have to configure and manage the instances running in the background yourself.

The preferred way of getting this to work on Google Cloud Platform would be using [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/). GCE gives you the option to create the instances in any region you want and configure a [Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/) to serve the traffic and scale your instances as you want. Here is some documentation about serving applications using GCE:

- [Running a GO app on Compute Engine (part of a GCP quickstart)](https://cloud.google.com/go/docs/tutorials/bookshelf-on-compute-engine)
- [Building Scalable and Resilient Web Applications on Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/scalable-and-resilient-apps)
- [Designing Robust Systems](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/robustsystems)

---

Also, here's a [Google Groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/3yqddF7UDy4) about this issue that goes a little bit more in detail.

Comment: Thanks Guillermo Cacheda! I'm aware of the option of migrating to GCE. However it requires quite some refactoring work for my current GAE app (which uses the old GoogleCloudDatastore) & quite some extra ongoing operating cost. So I'm hoping for a lower cost solution, given the 1 hour of downtime tolerance my app has. I'd love to able to keep having GAE to manage instances for me, in a region. Only when that region is down, I'll have to manually spin up the app in 2nd region. Will I be able remove GAE domain mapping on region 1, at that time, so that I can divert my clients traffic to region 2?

Comment: @David The option you are suggesting might work, and I've already seen multi-project App Engine setups using [Cloud Load Balancing](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/) to redirect traffic between regions. However, I can't really go into details here because is not a recommended setup for what you are looking for. If high availability is critical for your application, GCE is the only recommended way to go.